# Need help for writing a complex SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I need some help with a complex SQL query. 
Here's my setup: I have two tables `USER_TABLE` and `USER_VISIT_STAT`.
`USER_TABLE` have columns like `ID,USER_NAME,UID,DEPARTMENT` and
`USER_VISIT_STAT` have columns like `ID,USERID,LAST_VISIT_DATE`. `USERID` field of `USER_VISIT_STAT` table holds the `USER_TABLE.ID`.

When a user logs in to the application his current date is saved in `USER_VISIT_STAT` table (refer the screenshot). So I need to get the user details who are not connected to the application since last 2 years. But we have to take care of the `UID`. (means you can see in `USER_TABLE` there are two entries with same `UID` but case is different. In `USER_VISIT_STAT` u can see 101 `LAST_VISIT_DATE` is 31-08-18 and 103 `LAST_VISIT_DATE` is `20-01-16`. So you have to ignore both the ids because user is same and he is active). In response table I need user name, user uid, user department and user max(last active date).

```
+--------------------------------------+
|             USER_TABLE               |
+--------------------------------------+
| ID    | NAME    | UID   | DEPARTMENT |
+--------------------------------------+
| 101   | PRAKASH | US45  | ENGG       |
| 102   | RAJESH  | US22  | ENGG       |
| 103   | PRAKASH | us45  | HR         |
| 104   | HARI    |  US9  | ENGG       |
| 105   | MAYANK  | US90  | HR         |
+--------------------------------------+
+--------------------------------+
|          USER_VISIT_STAT       |
+--------------------------------+
| ID | USID | MAX(LAST_VISIT_DATE)|
+--------------------------------+
| 1  | 101 |    31-08-18         |
| 2  | 102 |    30-08-18         |
| 3  | 101 |    30-08-18         |
| 4  | 103 |    20-01-16         |
| 5  | 104 |    29-08-16         |
| 6  | 105 |    19-07-16         |
| 7  | 101 |    12-06-16         |
| 8  | 102 |    12-06-16         |
| 9  | 104 |    13-04-16         |
+--------------------------------+
+-------------------------------------------------+
|                    RESPONSE                     |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| NAME   | UID  |   DEPARTMENT | LAST_VISIT_DATE  |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| HARI   | US9  |   ENGG       |    29-08-16      |
| MAYANK | US09 |   HR         |  19-07-16        |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: have you already tried something? Or where exactly do you fail?

Comment: Yes, i am able to get uniq UID's which are not connected since past 2 years. but when i am trying to get there max(VISIT_DATE) proper result is not comming.

Comment: Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: in the text you mention `LAST_ACTIVE_DATE`, but I think this should be `LAST_VISIT_DATE`. If so then please change it.

Comment: Why do you use the caption `MAX(LAST_VISIT_DATE)`? Isn't this the column `LAST_VISIT_DATE`?

Comment: Thanx @miracle173

Comment: "But we have to take care of the UID" What does this mean? How is UID related to your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an analytic form of the MAX() function, partitioning that by the upper case of the UID will solve for this. 
Available as a demo here [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/24879/5)

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
  M.LAST_VISIT_DATE, U.*
FROM (
    SELECT
      U."UID" 
    , V.LAST_VISIT_DATE
    , MAX(V.LAST_VISIT_DATE) OVER(PARTITION BY UPPER(U."UID")) MAX_VISIT
    FROM USER_TABLE U
    INNER JOIN USER_VISIT_STAT V ON U.ID = V.USID
    ) M
INNER JOIN USER_TABLE U ON M."UID" = U."UID"
WHERE M.MAX_VISIT < ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-24)
AND M.LAST_VISIT_DATE = M.MAX_VISIT
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/24879/5/0)**:

```
|       LAST_VISIT_DATE |  ID |   NAME |  UID | DEPARTMENT |
|-----------------------|-----|--------|------|------------|
| 2016-08-29 00:00:00.0 | 104 |   HARI |  US9 |       ENGG |
| 2016-07-19 00:00:00.0 | 105 | MAYANK | US90 |         HR |
```

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE USER_TABLE
    ("ID" int, "NAME" varchar2(7), "UID" varchar2(4), "DEPARTMENT" varchar2(4))
;

INSERT ALL
    INTO USER_TABLE ("ID", "NAME", "UID", "DEPARTMENT")
         VALUES (101, 'PRAKASH', 'US45', 'ENGG')
    INTO USER_TABLE ("ID", "NAME", "UID", "DEPARTMENT")
         VALUES (102, 'RAJESH', 'US22', 'ENGG')
    INTO USER_TABLE ("ID", "NAME", "UID", "DEPARTMENT")
         VALUES (103, 'PRAKASH', 'us45', 'HR')
    INTO USER_TABLE ("ID", "NAME", "UID", "DEPARTMENT")
         VALUES (104, 'HARI', 'US9', 'ENGG')
    INTO USER_TABLE ("ID", "NAME", "UID", "DEPARTMENT")
         VALUES (105, 'MAYANK', 'US90', 'HR')
SELECT * FROM dual
;

CREATE TABLE USER_VISIT_STAT       
    ("ID" int, "USID" int, "LAST_VISIT_DATE" timestamp)
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO USER_VISIT_STAT        ("ID", "USID", "LAST_VISIT_DATE")
         VALUES (1, 101, '31-Aug-2018 12:00:00 AM')
    INTO USER_VISIT_STAT        ("ID", "USID", "LAST_VISIT_DATE")
         VALUES (2, 102, '30-Aug-2018 12:00:00 AM')
    INTO USER_VISIT_STAT        ("ID", "USID", "LAST_VISIT_DATE")
         VALUES (3, 101, '30-Aug-2018 12:00:00 AM')
    INTO USER_VISIT_STAT        ("ID", "USID", "LAST_VISIT_DATE")
         VALUES (4, 103, '20-Feb-2016 12:00:00 AM')
    INTO USER_VISIT_STAT        ("ID", "USID", "LAST_VISIT_DATE")
         VALUES (5, 104, '29-Aug-2016 12:00:00 AM')
    INTO USER_VISIT_STAT        ("ID", "USID", "LAST_VISIT_DATE")
         VALUES (6, 105, '19-Jul-2016 12:00:00 AM')
    INTO USER_VISIT_STAT        ("ID", "USID", "LAST_VISIT_DATE")
         VALUES (7, 101, '12-Jun-2016 12:00:00 AM')
    INTO USER_VISIT_STAT        ("ID", "USID", "LAST_VISIT_DATE")
         VALUES (8, 102, '12-Jun-2016 12:00:00 AM')
    INTO USER_VISIT_STAT        ("ID", "USID", "LAST_VISIT_DATE")
         VALUES (9, 104, '13-Apr-2016 12:00:00 AM')
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

Comment: I am getting proper result in fiddle. I am using oracle sql developer. So there its not working

Comment: @Prakashkumarmallick though you said not working but you accepted this answer

Comment: Its working fine now. So i accepted. But thanks for your help @Zaynul. I can't accept two answer otherwise i will accept your's also.This query is much simpler than yours so i accepted this. Anyway Thanks a lot Zaynul.

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin to inform you your query is also giving the proper result.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [`row_number`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions170.htm#SQLRF06100) to get the latest user details per `uid`, join them to the last visit date per `uid` and filter on that:

```
SELECT name, u.uid, department, max_visit
FROM   (SELECT name,
               uid,
               department,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY uid ORDER BY id DESC) AS rn
        FROM   user_table) u
JOIN   (SELECT   uid, MAX(last_visit_date) AS max_visit
        FROM     user_visit_stat
        GROUP BY uid
        HAVING   MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, MAX(last_visit_date)) >= 24) us ON u.uid = us.uid
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Comment: I think you might be missing a right parenthesis closing the nested SELECT in your join.

Comment: @BarryPiccinni I was missing the closing parenthesis of the `months_between` call. Edited and fixed, thanks for noticing!

Comment: @Mureinik (ON u.uid = us.uid ) u.uid and us.uid are not same u.id = us.uid. refer the above table properly.

Answer (score 1):

use aggregate function and join

```
  select u.*,t.last_visit from     
    (
   select min(ID) as ID ,Name, UPPER(UID) as UID,DEPARTMENT from USER_TABLE
    group by Name, UPPER(UID),DEPARTMENT
    ) as u 
    join
    (
    select UID,max(LAST_VISIT_DATE) as last_visit from USER_VISIT_STAT us
    group by UID 
    having max(LAST_VISIT_DATE) between  add_months(sysdate,-26) and add_months(sysdate,-24)
    ) as t
    on u.ID=t.UID
```

From conversation it seems to me you need below

```
select u.*, x.last_visit from
       (
       select Name, UPPER(UID) as UID,DEPARTMENT from USER_TABLE
        group by Name, UPPER(UID),DEPARTMENT
        ) as u 

        join
        (   
        select a.name,a.last_visit from
        (
        select distinct iu.NAME,last_visit from
        (
        select USID,max(LAST_VISIT_DATE) as last_visit from USER_VISIT_STAT us
        group by USID 
        having max(LAST_VISIT_DATE) between  add_months(sysdate,-26) and add_months(sysdate,-24)
        ) as t1 
        join
        USER_TABLE as iu on t1.USID=iu.ID
        ) a left join           

        (
        select distinct iu.NAME,    
        (
        select USID  from USER_VISIT_STAT us
        group by USID 
        having min(LAST_VISIT_DATE) between  add_months(sysdate,-23) and add_months(sysdate,0)
        ) as t1 
        join
        USER_TABLE as iu on t1.UID=iu.ID    
        ) b on a.NAME=b.NAME
        where b.NAME is null 
        ) x on u.Name=x.Name
```

Comment: Hi Zaynul. Is this query take care of UID case.

Comment: @Prakashkumarmallick yap

Comment: Means a user have two entries in G550_USER table where in one entry UID is in lowercase letter and another entry have uppercase UID. If  that user logedin recently from one UID and from another UID he not logedin since 2 year. In this case he should not be counted as inactive user.

Comment: does not matter cause filter will be applied on stat table and info will pick from user table

Comment: @Prakashkumarmallick user and userstat join is based on ID and UID of stat table so here no issue of upper or lower case

Comment: Ok @Zaynul. I am trying with this query. If it gives the proper response i will let you know.

Comment: @ Zaynul one more help. I need the interval from back 2.2 year to 2 year. means let today is 31-08-18. 2yr back date is 31-08-16. and 2.2yr back date is 31-06-16. so check should be between("31-06-16","31-08-16"). some thing like this.

Comment: @Prakashkumarmallick so you need 26 month before date?

Comment: users not active between from 26 to 24 month back

Comment: you can use in where clause this  for 26 month before date add_months(sysdate,-26)

Comment: It considering the active user also. user with id 103.

Comment: @Prakashkumarmallick 103 |    20-01-16 so last visit date was 2years ago

Comment: @Prakashkumarmallick check latest answer please

Comment: @Prakashkumarmallick if it helps please accept my answer as a SO appreciation

Comment: Hi @Zaynul, Your query is not giving uniq result. I told u that if a user have 2 uid with other cases and his one uid is active and second one is not active. then dont consider him in inactive user list

Comment: @Prakashkumarmallick have you faced problem ?

Comment: ya. same problem. uppercase lowercase issue

Comment: @Prakashkumarmallick could you give me sample data where you faced problem cause last day i solve your given data problem

Comment: prefer the above given table. See in USER_TABLE there are two user having same UID (US45 & us45). It means user is same but UID are entered in lowercase and uppercase. id of US45 is 101 and id of us45 is 103. Now refer USER_VISIT_STAT, u can notice that user having 101 ids LAST_VISIT_DATE is 31-08-2018 and of 103 is 20-01-16. So when we are geting the in active users from last 2year this user should not appear in response.

Comment: I think its not possible in query, i have to write procedure. Give me your suggestion.

Comment: Yes, both are same. But department is different.

Comment: @Prakashkumarmallick so when both user is same in that which id you will pick from USER_TABLE i pick minimum one

Comment: No, dont pick any of them if one visited recently.

Comment: @Prakashkumarmallick got the point ok just wait 10min i will response with correction

Comment: This is what my requirment is. If 101 LAST_VISIT_DATE is 31-08-2018 then dont pick 103. Because the user is active.

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
select a.uid,a.name,b.department,a.id,lastvisit
from
(select uid,name,max(id) as id
from USER_TABLE group by uid,name)a
inner join USER_TABLE b on a.uid=b.uid
inner join
(select uid,max(LAST_VISIT_DATE) as lastvisit
group by uid having max(LAST_VISIT_DATE)< trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy') - interval '2' year)x
on a.id=x.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
select uid,name,department,last_visit_date
from (
  select 
    a.id id, max(a.id) over (partition by a.uid) maxid,
    a.uid uid,a.name name,a.department department,
    max(last_visit_date) over (partition by a.uid) last_visit_date
  from 
    user_table a, user_visit_stat b
  where 
    a.id=b.uid
)
where last_visit_date<=add_years(sysdate,-2) and a.id=maxid
```